# Get duration of an HTML5 video (live stream)

Tags: html, video, live, http-live-streaming

I'm looking at options to switch from flash (strobe) to HTML5 solution (using Media Source Extensions with DASH or HLS).
According to the HTML5 specs for video we can't get the duration of a live stream video.

> The duration attribute must return the time of the end of the media resource,
>   in seconds, on the media timeline. If no media data is available, then the
>   attributes must return the Not-a-Number (NaN) value. If the media resource is
>   known to be unbounded (e.g. a streaming radio), then the attribute must return
>   the positive Infinity value.

My live stream is not a "sliding window" meaning that we have a fixed start date. I am currently using Strobe player and it actually increase the duration as it plays whereas HTML5 always returns `Infinity`.

I wanted to know if some options are available to maintain myself a duration (by parsing fragments for example, this [library](https://github.com/RReverser/mpegts) does that in a way).

Comment: Same here, infinity in iphone

Comment: Same problem here, tried to stop media track and then accessing video duration property but gives me Infinity.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough reputation to comment, so I'll type it here.

I think it's best to look into the `.seekable` and `.buffered` properties of the `HTMLMediaElement`. You can use the `.buffered` that returns a `TimeRanges` object to track the duration of the stream in your media but the media element itself has no means of knowing how long the stream might be.

The problem is that `.buffered` might not always tell you "how much stream" is there if you have pause for a long time, for example.

When I tested their behaviour on a Android virtual device and an HLS stream in Chrome, after several seconds of playback, buffered returned a `TimeRanges` object with length 1 and `video.buffered.end(0)` was 0, and `.seekable` returned the same thing but with `video.seekable.end(0) == Infinity`.

If you want precise data, I would agree that a parsing library, that parses the duration of a HLS playlist for example, is the best option, although not elegant at all.